# Getting the actual text response of a web page in java

Tags: java, http, yandex, yandex-api

I'm using java and trying to get the content of a website so that I can analyze the text on the page, however every time that I "GET" a response from the server, it is from a login page rather than the website page that I am looking at.

I am logged into the website on all my browsers, but my application is not able to see the page as if it were me.

I also tried to use an API called "Yandex" --> http://api.yandex.com/rca/
as a work-around.  But when I call the page from Yandex (which would get its content) I only see information based on the login page returned.

Can anyone give me a direction to investigate?  I would like to be able to get one item on the page of a website that I work for, but it doesn't seem possible.

```
m_strseedpath = "http://myUrl.com/mypage.html"; //not https    
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://rca.yandex.com/?key={MyActualKeyNotThisText}&url=" + m_strSeedUrlPath + "").openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(response, writer, "UTF-8");
String strString = writer.toString();

System.out.println(strString);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLConnection object will connect to the page but in a different session. You would have to programmaticaly log in from your Java code.

Create a URLConnection object to the login page, POST the user name and password, receive the content getting the InputStream from the URLConnection object, and finally create a new connection to the page you wish to analyze. You'd have to also work with cookies in order to view the second page.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The URL that you are trying to access has access restricted via login. Even if you are logged in via your browser you wont be able to access the page from your Java application because the browser has an Authenticated Session with the target website. The same session is not visible to your Java Application.

You would have to research into the ways to login to the website and then get the page content.

Comment: If I were to send the site cookie along with my request, would that solve the problem?  Even though the cookie is probably encrypted or whatever

Comment: I am not sure about that, you would have to try and see for yourself.
It might work. Also many browsers make use of sessionId for communicating between browser & the site, try using that too.

Comment: All the server sees is the http request. It doesn't care who is sending it. Intercept a request from your browser using fiddler, and replay it with Java. Has to work.